# Why could TPM be enabled in BIOS but not functional in OS?

Tags: windows-10, bios, tpm, hardware-detection, components

If the BIOS of a computer system shows that TPM is enabled then one would think this would mean the operating system would be able to use the TPM. However, this is not necessarily the case. The following images show the BIOS and operating system of a HP 290 GS2 SFF computer with Windows 10 Pro installed. As can be seen, the BIOS recognises TPM but the OS does not.

In this case...

1. The BIOS has been upgraded to the latest version.
2. Windows updates have been installed.
3. Scan performed for manufacturer updates (none available)
4. Scan performed within Windows for TPM driver updates (none available)
5. Secure boot enabled within the BIOS
6. Admin password set within the BIOS.
7. Fast boot disabled within Windows

What else, could be the cause of the TPM not being functional within Windows?

[image: BIOS - main]

[image: BIOS - security]

[image: Device Manager]

[image: TPM.msc]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/how-windows-uses-the-tpm    ....  TPM does not normally show up directly in Windows.

Comment: If this machine originally came with FreeDOS, then HP disabled through the "Feature Byte", only HP would be able to enable this functionality, if it was turned off when the machine was shipped by HP. However, the device is being detected, so my suggestion would be to use the "Clear TPM" option. Secure Boot has very little to do with TPM. I have a secondary system that has Secure Boot enable but is unable to use TPM due to the motherboard not supporting it.

Comment: @John - I don't agree with your assessment.  `tpm.msc` should be showing the TPM as being "ready to be used", the fact it's not indicating that, means while TPM is enabled it cannot be used with say BitLocker and/or other security features. What I can say is the author's processor supports Intel PTT since it was released after 2015. The real question is if HP disabled the feature on the motherboard when the machine was shipped.

Comment: Yes tpm.msc shows TPM ready for use.  I interpreted the question as showing up other ways.  I did not consider the "ready for use" screen.

Comment: The [i3-9100](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/134870/intel-core-i39100-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz/specifications.html) has TPM (Intel Trusted Execution Technology). The TPM firmware may not be updated, so you might try the [HP TPM Configuration Utility](https://support.hp.com/lv-en/document/c05381064).

Comment: Have you tried deleting the TPM device from Device Manager and letting Windows find it again ("Action" menu -> "Scan for hardware changes")?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, nice idea: uninstalled, restarted Windows, and automatically found without scan ... but still no TPM in TPM.msc